# Horizontal Scroll gallery missing scroll bar in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, horizontalscrollview

Having an issue in IE where my horizontal scroll bar is not showing up on my gallery Chrome and FF are working fine.

CSS

```
ul.images 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.images li 
{
display: inline;
height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="images">

<li><a target="base" href="text.jpg"><img src="test.jpg" height="160px" border="0" ></a></li>

<li><a target="base" href="test.jpg"><img src="test.jpg" Height="160px" border="0" ></a></li>

</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Works for me in IE8. I've put a border on the UL so you can see how wide it is. http://jsfiddle.net/55LgU/embedded/

Comment: Thanks for the border tip it seems to be dissapearing out of the IFrame downwards so it might be there but you cant see it.

Comment: Reduced the ul.images li height and it now works.

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing to see if IE would cooperate with code I wrote. It seemed to work, but you never mentioned what version of IE you were trying to use. I then tested another copy of your code with some minor modifications, and that seemed to work, too.
Since this probably will g
I tried IE7 and IE8, different browser modes and combinations. I dug around and found you this:
http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

I believe this covers many of the issues of this manner, but I wasn't sure of the accuracy. I tested his website under many of the conditions that I have available to me for IE testing, and he's quite accurate.

Hope this helps. Here's a JS fiddle I made to do some testing- It's a modified copy of your code, but I made sure to keep the CSS exact:

```
ul.images 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.images li 
{
display: inline;
height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H89WE/embedded/